# Pass Java Database results to JavaScript/PHP mobile websites

Tags: java, javascript, php, database, web

We're trying to make a mobile website that will be coded in JavaScript / PHP. We have a database that is queried and the results are retrieved using java code. How do I pass the results from my java code to the mobile website?

**edit** - 
the java connects to the database, queries the results, forms lists and passes it to the php/javascript code, that will display it in the website. There's no actual processing required in the PHP code. It's more like a bunch of functions in java do the work, while calling PHP modules to display the result in a webpage.

Comment: Wait. You have a PHP/JS site and you are retrieving database results using java. Why? PHP can do that.

Comment: Php can query the database. Why make it more complicated?

Comment: because the java code already exists with the database queries and results being handled in the java code. The interface of the website is to be made in PHP.

Comment: @kicker86 Then I think that the best option would be to port java code to PHP. Making java execute queries, waiting for it to get the results, then reading results with php and processing them would be a lot slower than making php execute queries and fetch results.

Comment: @BackSlash - what about getting the results - like a list, and passing it to PHP just to display, no processing required in PHP?

Comment: @kicker86 Surely it will work, but to me it's not a good thing to do. Why would one call a java application and wait for it to return queries results when PHP can do all the work?

Comment: @BackSlash: +1 for `port java code to PHP`

Comment: @BackSlash while I know that PHP can do all the code, and I understand that it's the best way to do this, but as I said, there's already a java backend that gets the results, and we need to put it into PHP. So I'm looking at ways to do that. Call it an exercise in futility!

Answer (score 0):

When you say Java, you mean something like WebLogic or TomCat servers? I guess it's not the case. I guess you can host your Java code in one of those servers and create webservices, that will serve data to your frontend PHP servers.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture for the general idea.